# Opposite of Torricelli's trumpet

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

[Torricelli's trumpet](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GabrielsHorn.html) (or Gabriel's horn) is an example of a solid figure with infinite surface area and finite volume.

Is it possible to build the opposite (finite surface area but infinite volume) in an n-dimensional space?
If not, how do we prove it?

More formally:

Let $S$ be an open subset of $\bf{ℝ^n}$ that is homeomorphic to $\bf{ℝ^n}$  and $S$ has infinite volume. If $T\cap \overline S\setminus S$  has a definable finite surface for every closed bounded $T\subset \Bbb R^n$, is it possible for $S$  to have finite area?

Comment: Note: asked at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242823/is-there-a-space-with-infinite-n-volume-but-a-boundary-of-finite-n-1-volu without answer. Conclusion there seems to be that the question needs to be presented a bit more rigorously.

Comment: See also 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046108/is-there-a-shape-with-infinite-area-but-finite-perimeter/1046112

Comment: @Travis The former is limited to three dimensions, the latter to two, so this is a duplicate of neither. Still good sources to look at though.

Comment: One of the prior duplicates of this Q says "I am not interested in figures such as  $\Bbb R^3 $ minus an open ball."   But that IS an example.  But intuitively it does not seem to match the phrase  "solid figure".  So I suggest that some restrictive definition  of what  a solid figure is, ( such as ????)  could make a good Q.

Comment: Suggestion: Let $S$ be an open subset of $\Bbb R^3$ that is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^3$ and $S$ has infinite volume. If $T\cap \overline S\setminus S$ has a definable finite area for every closed bounded $T\subset \Bbb R^3$ is the area, is it possible for $S$ to have finite area?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I can modify my question to this one. I can ask for  $\Bbb R^3$ as well as $\Bbb R^n$

Comment: @Y.Forman The present question asks first primarily about the 3D case---if this were not true, there would be not reason to mention it specifically when mentioning the general case anyway. I did not mean to suggest that the second link was also a duplicate, but rather, like you say, a source of some useful relevant ideas.

Comment: @Travis I was actually interested in the general n-dimensional case, but just thought the 3D case would be simpler, which is why I mentioned it specifically.

Comment: I ugest that you do make some modifications to the Q  before the site's moderators mark the Q as a duplicate, which  would make it highly unlikely to get new answers.